# Git Repository is not working in Azure Data Factory

Tags: git, azure, azure-data-factory

My Azure Data Factory disconnected the Github integration, therefore, I am not able to publish anything. It was working perfectly fine in the past, but once I have cleared my browser history data because it shot down unexpectedly, I couldn't connect to it again after that. I tried various browsers, laptops, and even allowed all types of 3rd party cookies, I keep getting the same issue over and over again. I tried it later on Windows Laptop using Microsoft edge browser and it worked, tried the same process on Macbook Pro, the issue is still standing. So, I am guessing it is a Mac issue!

Here is how the ADF when I sign into it:

1. When I sign in to adf.azure.com

[image]

2. Redirects me to this page

[image]

3. Redirects me to this page after I login with my github account, these are the present branches in my ADF

[image]

4. Even if I would like to disconnect the repo and plug it again, it does not allow me to do that, that's how it shows.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check first if, when clicking on the HOME icon, you see in the top right corner, the Git icon, as described [in this article](https://sqlplayer.net/2018/10/setting-up-code-repository-for-azure-data-factory-v2/) (and also seen here):

> ### Detach / remove Git (repo)
>
> Removing Git repo from Azure Data Factory is possible only in one place: Overview dashboard. In top-right corner you will see (or not. I haven’t for first time) small Git icon:
>
> [image: https://sqlplayer.net/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/235248-ADFv2-Overview-dashboard-with-assigned-repo.png]
>
> Clicking the icon you will gain access to information about attached GIT repository. At the bottom you’ll find “Remove Git” button. Once finish that – you can repeat the assigning process from the beginning.